# How to include dashes (or other special characters) in string concatenation?

Tags: linux, string, bash, symbols

So this may be a basic and trivial question, but I'm struggling with the usage of a dash/minus (-) in a string concatenation. (Actually with other symbols, like low bar, etc. too.)

Say, I've got 3 variables:

```
var1="${otherstring:0:4}"
var2="${otherstring:4:2}"
var3="${otherstring2:6:2}"
```

And I'd like to fuse them in the following way:

```
datap1="$var1$var2"-"$var3"
```

with the dash inserted in between.

The problem is that my output gets cut after the dash:

```
var1var2-
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT - adding the code:

```
#! /bin/sh -

find . -type f -mtime -7 | sed "s|^\./||" | xargs -n1 gunzip
var1=$(ls -t *.log | head -n1 | sed 's/.log$//' | egrep -o '.{1,8}$')
var2=$(ls -t *.log | tail -n1 | sed 's/.log$//' | egrep -o '.{1,8}$')
any1="${var1:0:4}"
any2="${var2:0:4}"
mes1="${var1:4:2}"
mes2="${var2:4:2}"
dia1="${var1:6:2}"
dia1="${var2:6:2}"
if [ "$any1" == "$any2" ]; then
    if [ "$mes1" == "$mes2" ]; then
        datap1="$any1$mes1$dia1"-"$dia2"
    else
        datap1="$any1$mes1$dia1"-"$mes2$dia2"
    fi
else
    datap1="$any1$mes1$dia1"-"$any2$mes2$dia2"
fi
/usr/local/exim/bin/eximstats -nr -t0 -nt -xls *.log > stats_01_"$datap1".xls
find . -type f -name "*.log" | sed "s|^\./||" | xargs -n1 gzip
```

And I run that as a *.sh* file.

[The first part of the code is just to get the necessary part for the string manipulation, the logs contain the date at the end of their name. The log files are of the sort *"foo_bar_foo_20190410.log"*. The if loop is just some date comparison/sorting.]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See https://ideone.com/eU8Wil it prints `var1var2-var1`

Comment: Well, in `shell` variable truncate does not work that way, so you're using `bash`, not `shell`. And in `bash` it works fine...

Comment: Do you use Windows line endings? CRLF? Then the first `var1` might actually be the second one overwriting the first.

Comment: @muru if that would be the case `var2` would overwrite `var1`

Comment: @kvantour not necessarily, they're substrings of some other string, and that other string may have CRLF inside it.

Comment: Can you give us an [mcve], what are the values of `otherstring` and `otherstring2`

Comment: I've added the whole code, which I run as a .sh script.

Comment: You have a typo: `dia1="${var2:6:2}"` should be `dia2="${var2:6:2}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works as expected for me.

You don't even need to put the dash outside the quotes, this works also:

```
datap1="$var1$var2-$var1"
```

The case where you need to do something special is if the separator character is allowed as part of a variable name, e.g. underscore. If you write

```
datap1="$var1$var2_$var1"
```

it will try to find a variable named `var2_`, and it will fail, so nothing will be substituted; the value will be `var1var1`. You can put braces around the variable name to delimit it:

```
datap1="$var1${var2}_$var1"
```

Comment: That is strange, I've already tried the two ways of concatenation and none is working, my output still gets cut after the dash/bar.

Comment: What do you see if you do `echo "$datap1" | od -c`? Do you see `\r` in the output?

Comment: I got the following: ```0000000   2   0   1   9   0   4   0   3   -  \n
0000012
```

Comment: You never set `$dia2`, you set `$dia1` twice.

Comment: Thank you! That sums it all!

Comment: Why did you accept this answer? It's not at all related to the real problem you had.

Comment: Because it clarifies the question in first place, even if my problem was different. I wasn't very sure if the concatenation was correct, it was just a supposition and since I wasn't obtaining the correct output, I could have no clue about the usage of the dash/bar/etc in a string.